# ionic - Overriding component's SASS variables not working for iOS

Tags: ionic-framework, sass

I have a simple page (screen):

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-searchbar
      placeholder="Search"
      (ionInput)="filterItems($event)"
      [showCancelButton]="true"
      cancelButtonText="Cancel"></ion-searchbar>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Referring to the [official documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/):

> There are many variables you can override with Ionic. Any of the following variables can be overridden from your src/theme/variables.scss file, just add a new value to the file...

I want to change the background of the input in the search bar component. I found that I should override this variable:

```
/// @prop - Background of the searchbar input inside of a toolbar
$searchbar-ios-toolbar-input-background:  rgba(0, 0, 0, .08) !default;
```

declared in: `MyProject/node_modules/ionic-angular/components/searchbar/searchbar.ios.scss:58`

So, as per the docs, in my `MyProject/src/theme/variables.scss` under the comment that suggests putting iOS specific app-wide styles I add:

```
// App iOS Variables
// --------------------------------------------------
// iOS only Sass variables can go here

$searchbar-ios-toolbar-input-background: #fff;
```

But the input has the same background defined in the original component's styles. If I add `!important` after the color in the statement above, everything works.

If I try overriding the same thing but for Android devices (Material Design variables) it works without adding `!important`.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Actually, any variable for that component is not "overwritebale" without `!important`.

Comment: That is the wrong spot for overriding the ionic sass vars. Look nearer the top of the variables.scss Just above where the colors are defined you will see this // Shared Variables
// --------------------------------------------------
// To customize the look and feel of this app, you can override
// the Sass variables found in Ionic's source scss files.
// To view all the possible Ionic variables, see:
// http://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/

Comment: I moved them to the `Shared variables` "section" and it's still not working as expected. (I need to specify it's `!important`.)

Comment: If you are overriding from the variables.scss there is no need for !important. Only if you try to change the values after compiling will you need !important. Have you tried running ionic serve again after making the change?

Comment: Yes, this is what I am expecting. However, it no styles are applied unless I use `!important`. I tried running `ionic serve` again, without `!important` on the rules, nothing is changed.

Comment: If I remove `color="primary"` from `ion-toolbar`, everything is fine. How can I overwrite the variables with that attribute `color="primary"`?

Comment: I just tested in a blank project, $searchbar-ios-toolbar-input-background works without !important, but as you say the toolbar cannot have color input. If over ridding the css locally is an option. Set the color attribute and then locally setting the input background color with .toolbar-ios-light .searchbar-ios .searchbar-input {
    background-color:  blue !important;
}. Or you could do it vice versa.